# In CSS what is the difference between display:block vs clear:both

Tags: css

In addition to the question stated in the title, I also conversely would like to know how is display:inline different from clear:none?

EDIT: I had a hunch this question would be unpopular... let me elaborate.

Both seem to involve putting elements onto their own line.  "display:inline" flows elements inline, which strikes me as very similar to the behavior of "clear:none", which allows elements to float next to you.

Conversely if you want your div, perhaps a footer as in this example https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/, to stand on its own then you can say "clear:both" indicating that nothing may float next to you.

But this behavior seems very similar to "display:block".

Hence my question, how are these different in behavior or expected usage?

I'm sure it's obvious by now that I'm a total amateur in CSS, but after 15 years in backend programming I'm trying to face my fears and learn it.  I hope someone might answer the question rather than downvoting me for trying to learn something new...

Answer (score 0):

`display:block` -> Displays an element as a block element (like `<p>`)

`clear:both` -> No floating elements allowed on either the left or the right side

A **block-level element** always **starts on a new line** and takes up the full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it can).

An **inline element does not start on a new line** and only takes up as much width as necessary.

Comment: The OP is asking for the difference between display:block and clear:both. They both seem to go on a new line.